# Difficulty making a javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, error-handling, undefined

I am making a website for a school project and want to implement a javascript game, I've gotten pretty far before running into this error. most error's I've been able to fix but this one i'm not able to. My teacher doesn't know the answer either so I hope I can find some help here

here's my code

```
            var player;

            function startgame() {
                gamearea.start();
                playerupdater();
                player = new component(30, 30, "blue", 10, 120);
            }

            var gamearea = {
                canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
                start : function() {
                    this.canvas.width = 480;
                    this.canvas.height = 270;   
                    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                    this.interval = setInterval(updateplayer, 50);
                },
                clear : function(){
                    console.log(this)
59------>           this.canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); <-
                }
            }

            function playerupdatetimeout(){
                setTimeout(playerupdater, 25)
            }

            function playerupdater(){
                setInterval(gamearea.clear, 50);
            }

            function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.speedx = 0;
                this.speedy = 1;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y; 
                this.update = function(){   
                    ctx = gamearea.context;
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
                this.newpos = function(){
                    this.x += this.speedx;
                    this.y += this.speedy;
                }
            }

            function updateplayer(){
                player.update();
            }

            function movup(){
                player.speedy -=1;  
            }

            function movdown(){
                player.speedy +=1;
            }

            function movright(){
                player.speedx -=1;
            }

            function movleft(){
                player.speedx +=1;
            }
```

the console states that there is an error in line 59 (which Is indicated in the code itself)

if you want to see the error yourself my website is online right here: https://jessep2000.github.io./home.html

and all my code used for this page is in this repository
https://github.com/Jessep2000/Jessep2000.github.io/tree/master

hope someone knows the answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: `setInterval(gamearea.clear, 50);` changes the `this` value inside the clear function, you can fix this writing `setInterval(gamearea.clear.bind(gamearea), 50);`

Comment: Thank you! It made the error go away but now the console gives this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.canvas.clearRect is not a function
    at Object.clear (home.html:59)"

Answer (score 0):

**In line 59 `this.canavas` is undefined** because you are trying to access the object key from within the same object . Make another object like :-

```
let obj ={
clear : function(){       
   this.gamearea.canavas.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); <-
    }
}
```

When you want to use clear function just use:

```
obj.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Roland Starke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378743/roland-starke) and [Shivendra Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9247465/shivendra-gupta) for solving my problem, this is the eventual result:

```
var player;
function startgame() {
                gamearea.start();
                playerupdater();
                player = new component(30, 30, "blue", 10, 120);
            }
                let obj ={
                    clear : function(){       
                         this.gamearea.canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); 
                     }
                }
            var gamearea = {
                canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
                start: function () {
                    this.canvas.width = 480;
                    this.canvas.height = 270;
                    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                    this.interval = setInterval(updateplayer, 50);
                },
                clear: function() {
                    let ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
                }
            }
            function playerupdatetimeout(){
                setTimeout(playerupdater, 25)
            }
            function playerupdater(){
                setInterval(gamearea.clear.bind(gamearea), 50);
            }
            function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.speedx = 0;
                this.speedy = 1;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y; 
                this.update = function(){   
                    ctx = gamearea.context;
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
                this.newpos = function(){
                    this.x += this.speedx;
                    this.y += this.speedy;
                }
            }
            function updateplayer(){
                player.update();
            }
            function movup(){
                player.speedy -=1;  
            }
            function movdown(){
                player.speedy +=1;
            }
            function movright(){
                player.speedx -=1;
            }
            function movleft(){
                player.speedx +=1;
            }
```

Im now working on getting the timing on the clear and player update function. Thank you guys for your help!